Question about the resulting polynomial evaluating one of the variables at an algebraic number?
This is a question in algebraic number theory I have been trying to figure out. Suppose I have two polynomials $F (x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ with rational coefficients. Let $\alpha \in \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ be an algebraic number with minimal polynomial $f$.
Suppose it turns out that $F(x, \alpha)$ and $G(x, \alpha)$ share a common factor as polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)[x]$. What can I deduce about the original polynomials $F (x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$?

A question on the notation. Is it important that the minimal polynomial is denoted by $f$? We are only using $F$ and $G$ later on. What is the origin of this question? Did you do an example?

It's not necessary for the question, but wanted to include in case the minimal polynomial would come in...

Please include additional details like the source of the question, your attempt(s). Otherwise, your question can attract downvotes and close votes.

I don't see what we can deduce. To see this, I wanted to understand an example, for $\alpha=i$ and $f=x^2+1$. But then, say, consider
$$
F(x,y)=x^4y^3+x^3y^2+xy^2,\quad G(x,y)=x^5y^2+x^3y^4.
$$
The polynomials $F(x,\alpha)=-x^4i-x^3-x$ and $G(x,\alpha)=-x^5+x^3$ have a common factor $x$, even over $\Bbb Q[x]$. But there seems to be no way to deduce something interesting on the original polynomials. Of course, they also have a common factor $x$ in this case (and a factor $xy^2$).
